# Bootstrap no aplica el sorting en datatables

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Estoy arreglando una aplicación en laravel 5.2 heredada en la cual aparecen varias tablas, y como algunos de los datos que se cargan en esas tablas son ciertamente densos, me han pedido que las tablas cuenten con una ordenación, en un principio he visto que la aplicación tiene instalado Bootstrap, y que puedo tirar de las clases de bootstrap para hacer la ordenación por columnas con las clases "dataTables" para la tabla y con la clase "sorting" para que aparezca la opción de ordenación en las columnas, pero parece ser que por mucho que use la clase y que busque opciones para implementarla no soy capaz de que se ordenen las columnas.

El trozo de código correspondientes a mi problema es:

```js
var oleada_ids = $('#oleadas').val();
var nodos_ids = $('#nodos').val();
var proyecto_id = parseInt("{{$proyecto->getId()}}");
$.ajax({
      url: "{{URL::to("
      clientes / get - resumen - oleadas ")}}",
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
        proyecto_id: proyecto_id,
        filtros: JSON.stringify(filtros_values),
        oleada_ids: oleada_ids,
        nodos_ids: nodos_ids,
        filtros_options: resultado_filtros
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        divLoader.show();
      },
      success: function(data) {
          informes_id = data.informes_id;
          resumenContainer.empty();
          if (data.preguntas.length === 0) {
            resumenContainer.append('<div class="alert alert-warning" style="text-align:center"><strong>No hay nada que mostrar</strong></div>')
          }
          var numeroPregunta = 1;
          var numeroBloque = 1;
          $.each(data.preguntas, function(a, b) {
            var htmlContent = '<div class="col-md-12 panel panel-primary"><div class="panel-heading">' + a + '</div><div class="panel-body">';
            var chartsValues = {};
            $.each(b, function(key, value) {

              var links = '';
              var content = '';
              var resumen = '<table class="table table-striped dataTable" style="width:100%;padding:20px;">';
              resumen += '<thead> <th class="sorting">Respuestas</th><th class="sorting">Puntuación</th><th class="sorting">Porcentaje</th></thead>';
              var answersValues = {};
              var subIndex = 0;
              var sumatorioMedia = 0.00;
              var totalPreguntas = 0;
              $.each(value['respuestas'], function(key1, value1) {
                links += '<li><a  class="respuesta-informe" data-pregunta-id="' + value["pregunta_id"] + '" data-respuesta-id="' + value1['id'] + '" data-respuesta-literal="' + key1 + '" id="' + value["pregunta_id"] + '-' + subIndex + 'Tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#' + value["pregunta_id"] + '-' + subIndex + '"><i class="m-r-10">&emsp;</i>' + key1 + '</a></li>';
                content += '<div id="' + value["pregunta_id"] + '-' + subIndex + '" class="tab-pane fade">' +
                  '<table class="table table-striped dataTable" style="width:100%;padding:20px;">' +
                  '<thead><tr><th class="sorting">@lang('
                clientes / extra.nombre.completo ')</th><th class="sorting"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> @lang('
                clientes / extra.fecha ')</th><th class="sorting">@lang('
                clientes / extra.puntuacion ')</th><th>@lang('
                clientes / extra.comentario ')</th><th>@lang('
                clientes / extra.exportar ')</th></tr></thead>' +
                  '<tbody id="respuesta-informe-' + value["pregunta_id"] + '-' + value1['id'] + '">';

                content += '</tbody></table></div>';

                var percent = Math.round(value1['total'] / value['total_respuestas'] * 10000) / 100;
                answersValues[key1] = percent;
                resumen += '<tr><td><strong>' + key1 + ':</strong></td><td>' + value1['total'] + '</td><td>(' + percent + '%)</td> ';
                subIndex++;
                if (!value1['no_procede']) {
                  sumatorioMedia += value1['total'] * value1['puntuacion'];
                  totalPreguntas += value1['total'];
                }

              });
              var media = sumatorioMedia / totalPreguntas;
              media = media.toFixed(2);
              if (media !== "NP") {
                var sumatorioDesviacionTipica = 0.00;
                $.each(value['respuestas'], function(key1, value1) {
                  if (!value1['no_procede']) {
                    sumatorioDesviacionTipica += Math.pow((value1['puntuacion'] - media), 2) * value1['total'];
                  }
                });
                var desviacionTipica = Math.sqrt(sumatorioDesviacionTipica / (totalPreguntas - 1));
                desviacionTipica = desviacionTipica.toFixed(2);
              }

              if (isNaN(media)) {
                media = "NP";
                desviacionTipica = "NP";
              }

              resumen += "<tr style='border-top: 2px solid black;'><td><strong>@lang('clientes/extra.total.respuestas'):</strong></td><td><strong>" + value['total_respuestas'] + "</strong></td><td></td></tr></table>";
              htmlContent += '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
                '               <div class="panel-heading white" style="margin-bottom:10px">' +
                numeroPregunta + '. ' + key +
                '               </div>' +
                '               <div class="panel-body">' +
                '                   <div class="row">' +
                '                       <div id="chart' + value["pregunta_id"] + '" class="col-md-3" style="width:200px;height:200px">' +
                '                           <div class="media">' +
                '                               <div class="capaLiteralMedia">' +
                '                                   <p class="literalMedia">@lang('
              clientes / extra.media '): </p>' + media +
                '                               </div>' +
                '                               <div class="capaLiteralDesviacion">' +
                '                                   <p class="literalDesviacion">@lang('
              clientes / extra.desviacion.tipica '): ' + '</p>' + desviacionTipica +
                '                               </div>' +
                '                           </div>' +
                '                       </div> ' +
                '                       <div class="col-md-10">' +
                '                           <ul id="' + value["pregunta_id"] + '" class="nav nav-tabs">' +
                '                               <li class="active">' +
                '                                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#resumen' + value["pregunta_id"] + '">@lang('
              clientes / extra.resumen ')</a>' +
                '                               </li>' +
                links +
                '                           </ul>' +
                '                           <div class="tab-content" style="height:300px;overflow-y:auto;margin-top:0;">' +
                '                               <div id="resumen' + value["pregunta_id"] + '" class="tab-pane fade in active">' +
                resumen +
                '                               </div>' +
                content +
                '                           </div>' +
                '                       </div> ' +
                '                   </div> ' +
                '               </div>' +
                '           </div>';

              numeroPregunta++;
              chartsValues[value['pregunta_id']] = answersValues;
            });
            htmlContent += '</div></div>';
            numeroBloque++;
            resumenContainer.append(htmlContent);
            $.each(chartsValues, function(chartKey, chartValues) {
              doChart(chartKey, chartValues);
            })
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Yo ya llevo un par de días dándole vueltas a por que no funciona la ordenación, espero que vosotros podáis echarme una mano con esto.

Un saludo a todos y gracias por llegar leyendo hasta aquí.

Comment: Que tipo de complemento para tablas usas? No se ve la parte de la tabla donde harás el 'sorting'

Comment: Pues en este caso el complemento para datatables que se usa en la aplicación es el yajra/datatables.

Comment: No me carga ni la documentación, ni los ejemplos..

Comment: La documentación y los ejemplos de yajra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder utilizar `dataTable` primeramente debes iniciar la tabla, te dejo un ejemplo, para utilizar el "sorting" solo utiliza `"order": [[3]]` u la columna por la cual requieres ordenar los datos y debes cargar las librerías para `dataTable`. Para más información y ejemplos puedes consultar esta liga: https://datatables.net/examples/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        /*Ordenar columnas*/
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Al final después de dar muchas vueltas y partirme la cabeza, me puse a repasar los scripts de librerías que usaba la aplicación para generar las tablas, y encontré que los que gestionaban antes la aplicación estaban cargando librerías de bootstrap ya obsoletas para generar las tablas, por lo que al final implementando las librerías por defecto de datatables en el blade donde se cargaba la tabla, conseguí que funcionase el sistema de ordenación de columnas. Muchas gracias a todos por pasaros a echar un cable.